# How to substitute all numbers in a string by one single character

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Is there a way I can substitute **all numbers** in a string for **one single character**?

For example,
if I have a string like this

```
abc123xyz
```

I want this:

```
abc*xyz
```

At the moment I do it like this:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "[0-9]", with: "*", options: .regularExpression)
```

resulting in:

```
abc***xyz
```

but this replaces every number with * which is not what I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `of: "[0-9]+"` is what you need.

Comment: this is it! Thank you @Xufox! If you put it as a response I can mark it as the valid one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regex quantifier `+` if you want to match at least one digit rather than exactly one:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "[0-9]+", with: "*", options: .regularExpression)
```